# Add document to sub-collection of an empty document with a randomly generated id in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an empty new "Book" document in firestore with a randomly generated uid. At the same time I'd like to add data to a "Page" document in a subcollection called "Pages" within the book document. I haven't been able to make this work, do I need to explicitly reference a docId before writing to a subcollection?

```js
    export const addBookAndFirstPage = () => {
      const pageRef = db.collection("books").doc().collection("pages").doc("page1");
      return pageRef.set({ foo: "bar" });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by creating the two references to each doc individually but also using `add()` instead of *doc()* as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). Note that `add()` **expects to take an object as an argument otherwise it throws the following exception**:

> FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Data must
> be an object, but it was: undefined

To create an empty document with a randomly generated uid we need to pass an empty object to the `add` method like below. We can then create the reference for the doc we intent to add to the subcollection and set data:

```js
export const addBookAndFirstPage = async () => {
  try {
    let bookRef = await db.collection("books").add({});   // <--- Use add() with an empty object
    let pageRef = await caseRef.collection("pages").doc("page1");
    return await pageRef.set({ foo: "bar" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```